# Orbeon if statement based on data type

Tags: orbeon, formbuilder

I'm using a piece of code that clears the input of any non relevant field, but it doesn't work if the type of that field is a file upload. I'm wanting to use an if statement in the creation of this setvalue to decide whether or not to proceed with setting the value to blank. I've tried a number of ways around this but haven't found anything that has worked.
Cheers

```
<xf:action observer="fr-form-group" event="xforms-disabled" ref="event('xxf:binding')">
    <xf:setvalue if="./@type ='fr-attachment'"/>                             
</xf:action>
```

Comment: Hi Levi, the `event('xxf:binding')` will point to the element in the instance to which the control is bound. You can see what it looks like by, in Form Builder, in the Advanced tab, clicking on Edit Source. This element will look like `<control-2 filename="" mediatype="" size=""/>`. So in your test, you could maybe try something like `if="exists(@filename)"`. You'll let me know if this works for you. -Alex

Comment: This works great on standard form sections, and your technique for finding the type works perfectly. Now the only issue I'm facing is that I need this action to apply to a library as well, as our forms are probably more reusable sections then not. Any ideas how I could apply this to a library?

Thanks for your help,
Levi

Comment: Hi Levi, I imagine that you're referring to the section templates. Controls in a section template is encapsulated in an XBL component, so events don't normally "flow" outside of the component. However, you can catch those events by adding `xxf:phantom="true"` on your handler. You'll let me know if that works in this case. And for more on this, see the doc on [phantom handlers](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/events/events-extensions-other#phantom-handlers). ‑Alex

Comment: Oh man that's perfect, now the only problem we're facing is that you can't use it with repeated sections. This is such a handy event to work with though, thanks for all your help. I feel like this is a poorly known but very powerful technique, here is what I did in the end:
`<xf:action observer="fr-form-group" event="xforms-disabled" xxf:phantom="true"
                       ref="event('xxf:binding')">
   <xf:setvalue if="(not (exists(@filename))) and not( fr:is-readonly-mode())"/>                             
</xf:action>`

Comment: Cool, I'm glad this works! But you're saying that this doesn't work for you when you have repeated sections? ‑Alex

Comment: Yeah, I read somewhere on github there was a problem with xxf:phantom causing crashes so it was turned off for repeated sections so I'm guessing that's why it isn't working for them.

Comment: Got it Levi, I see you're referring to [issue 3502](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3502). I've added a +1 from you on that one. ‑Alex

Comment: This was working great, but I've now found that our repeated sections are not working at all with this added. When we remove a section from the repeated section it causes the form to stop working completely at times. If the fields in the repeated section are full (we have two plain text, one date, and a fileupload)  we get this error 
Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException and the form stops responding.